# How to perform join on collection using mapreduce mongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mapreduce

Hey guys i'm working on my mini project of DBMS mongoDB.
I have two collection named as "Consumers" and "Bills".

The Consumer collection contain consumer number, consumer information with an area code. Also the Bills contail Consumer number,  Bill month (Bill month = "YYMM") , Bill amount. 
Now i want the monthly total bill amount of an perticular area code.

Please help...

 My Collection schema is

Consumer

+--> "Consumer_Number" int

+--> "Consumer_Name" string

+--> "Area_Code" int


Bills

+--> "Bill_Number" int

+--> "Consumer_Number" int

+--> "Bill_Month" int

+--> "Bill_Amount" int



 I want output as

{
   Consumer_Number : "1234",
   Area_Code : "02",
   Bill_Amount_01 : "234",
   Bill_Amount_02 : "404",
   Bill_Amount_03 : "534",
   Bill_Amount_04 : "200",
   Bill_Amount_05 : "150",
   Bill_Amount_06 : "190",
   Bill_Amount_07 : "150",
   Bill_Amount_08 : "300",
   Bill_Amount_09 : "450",
   Bill_Amount_10 : "540",
   Bill_Amount_11 : "230",
   Bill_Amount_12 : "600",
}

Comment: A quick google search will get you a lot of results for this however, I recommend you do not follow this path, it will not work well, mapreduce was never designed for such a thing

Answer (score 0):

In MongoDB, you can't perform join among two collections by either map-reduce or by using queries. But in your case, you can re-design your collections by making use of  Embedded documents approach. Embedded Documents approach will have little cost in terms of space but query performance would be great.

In your example, you can make **Consumer** Collection entries as an embedded document of **Bills** Collection. Sample Document would look something like this,

```
{
  "Bill_Number": "Bill 1",
  "Bill_Month" : "June",
  "Bill_Amount" : "1000",
  "Consumer" : { 
                 "Consumer_Number": "Consumer 1",
                 "Consumer_Name ": " John ",
                 "Area_Code":"Area Code 1"
                }
}
```

Now you don't have to even write map-reduce code, you can retrieve using mongo queries itself.

Comment: Sorry my friend, but in our project the condition is there should not be any data redundancy (repetation). Also while editing any information of consumer, the problem may occur.